# Windows Store向けのビルドに関するエラー

Tags: unity3d, windows-store-apps

Unityを使ってゲームを開発してます。
このたびWindows Store向けにビルドしたところ
 The name 'ServicePointManager' does not exist in the current context
というエラーがでました。
ほかのプラットフォームではでなかったです。

調べたところコンパイラーが違うなどの情報がありますが、具体的になにをすればいいのかわかりません。解決方法をおしえてください。

[マルチポスト](https://teratail.com/questions/78255?nli=592fb482-8474-44f6-ae39-5a700a000318#reply-123702)です

https://docs.unity3d.com/jp/540/Manual/windowsstore-missingtypes.html
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.net.servicepointmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーの箇所はnifty cloud mobile backendの部分だったのですが，これはWindows storeに対応していないということがわかりました。
https://github.com/NIFTYCloud-mbaas/ncmb_unity